# Showing external content on site, without security issues

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a website, in which I refer to external content, that is, in other websites
I would like to have the content shown to the fullest extent, but I do not wish to through the user away from my website

The current solution I have for this issue is a menu bar and an iframe, that takes most of the screen.

The thing is, that more and more websites are preventing from their content being displayed inside iframes, for security risks

A JavaScript type solution might encounter CORS issue, essentially not bypassing the main issue

Is there a "correct" way of displaying external content without trigggering security issues, with html5 standards, JavaScript, etc. ?

Comment: Is this external content maintained by you, or is it third-party? If it's the former, there are measures you can take. If it's the latter, you'll face an uphill battle since of course the security models that are in place are there to protect the interests of the site owner.

Comment: the latter. If the external content was my own, I could control the entire process. The thing is, it's not...

Comment: Are you in a partnership with the owners of the external content? If so, they can whitelist your site's origin. If you're using their content without permission on your site, hopefully you can see the conflict.

Comment: Tye external sites are multiple... the idea is to refer users to external content on the web, but I don't want to draw them off my site. using a iframe, the external content owner receives a new visitor with his ads displayed, etc. of course, the security issues rise, hence my question

Comment: Makes sense. I'm not sure there's any great solutions for you. Perhaps you could provide a link near the iframe for the user to open it in a new window in case the frame doesn't work. The other option would be to proxy the request through your server and fetch the external page from your back-end. If the user's cookies for that external site matter, of course that would have its own limitations.

Comment: @Jacob I have a link to the direct page and the external eebsite's main page. passing the content via server creates a whole new set of issues... I practically want to use iframes for one of their original purposes